# Где можно найти исходники стилей, отмеченные префиксом "avares", или как стилизовать Header Expaner'а

Tags: c#, xaml, avalonia, стилизация

Мне нужно посмотреть исходник файла со стилями, чтобы понять, как правильно стилизовать визуальный элемент. Эти стили можно подключить, добавив строку в файл `App.axaml`:

```
<StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
```

В частности это используется в проекте https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone

При поиске в гугл `Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml` нужный исходник в поиске не обнаруживается. В репозитории https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia тоже не могу найти файл `DefaultTheme.xaml` по указанному адресу. Он мне нужен только для того, чтобы посмотреть теги и аттрибуты для стилизации. Подключить его не годится - мне нужны не все стили.

Что мне на самом деле нужно: как достучаться и стилизовать `Expander`, уменьшить отступы внутри Header'а

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас Header занимает много место. Мне не нужно столько свободного пространства вокруг слова слова "Название", я хочу сделать убористо. Если я в `App.axaml` добавлю строку `StyleInclude`, приведённую мной выше, то получится вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. выше слова "Название" интервал уменьшился. Но мне не нужны все стили оттуда, в частности, я не хочу, чтобы надпись "Название" исчезала при открытии Expandera.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, но лучше всего - помочь найти XAML-файл, чтобы подробнее и на конкретном примере узнать о том, как стилизовать визуальные элементы

Comment: Могу подсказать где лежит тема FluentAPI: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls

Comment: @СергейЗагороднев спасибо)